# Disjoint-set data structure (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, union-find

I'm an intermediate-level C++ programmer aiming to write reference-quality code. I hope to learn about any mistakes in this piece of code and blind spots in my understanding of concepts. Notes:

- The stylistic use of `public:`/`private:` on every member is subject of a [question on Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/346836/).
- I'm not totally sure if I made the best choice by having the assignment operator take an object by value, instead of defining two separate assignment operators for copy-by-reference and move-by-rvalue-reference.
- I intend to avoid all undefined behavior on all platforms. I care very much about things like integer bit width guarantees, integer type conversion rules, signed integer overflows, etc.
- If a feature like `struct`/`class` has a C flavor and C++ flavor, I generally prefer the C++ flavor. (An exception is that I prefer value construction with `=` instead of `()` or `{}`.)

---

### Sample usage:

```cpp
DisjointSet<std::uint16_t> ds(4);
ds.mergeSets(2, 0);
std::cout << ds.getNumberOfSets() << std::endl;  // 3
std::cout << ds.areInSameSet(0, 2)) << std::endl;  // true
```

(For further examples, see the accompanying [test program](https://www.nayuki.io/res/disjoint-set-data-structure/DisjointSetTest.cpp).)

### Library:

<sub>[download](https://www.nayuki.io/res/disjoint-set-data-structure/DisjointSet.hpp)</sub>

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


/* 
 * Represents a set of disjoint sets. Also known as the union-find data structure.
 * Main operations are querying if two elements are in the same set, and merging two sets together.
 * Useful for testing graph connectivity, and is used in Kruskal's algorithm.
 * The parameter S can be any integer type, such as size_t. For any given S, the maximum number
 * of sets is S_MAX. Using a smaller type like int8_t can help save memory compared to uint64_t.
 */
template <typename S>
class DisjointSet final {
    
    /*---- Helper structure ----*/
    
    private: struct Node final {
        // The index of the parent element. An element is a representative
        // iff its parent is itself. Mutable due to path compression.
        mutable S parent;
        
        // Always in the range [0, floor(log2(numElems))]. For practical computers, this has a maximum value of 64.
        // Note that signed char is guaranteed to cover at least the range [0, 127].
        signed char rank;
        
        // Positive number if the element is a representative, otherwise zero.
        S size;
    };
    
    
    
    /*---- Fields ----*/
    
    private: std::vector<Node> nodes;
    private: S numSets;
    
    
    
    /*---- Constructors ----*/
    
    // Constructs a new set containing the given number of singleton sets.
    // For example, DisjointSet(3) --> {{0}, {1}, {2}}.
    // Even if S has a wider range than size_t, it is required that 1 <= numElems <= SIZE_MAX.
    public: explicit DisjointSet(S numElems) :
            numSets(numElems) {
        if (numElems < 0)
            throw std::domain_error("Number of elements must be non-negative");
        if (!safeLessEquals(numElems, SIZE_MAX))
            throw std::length_error("Number of elements too large");
        nodes.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(numElems));
        for (S i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
            nodes.push_back(Node{i, 0, 1});
    }
    
    
    public: explicit DisjointSet(const DisjointSet &other) = default;
    
    
    public: DisjointSet(DisjointSet &&other) = default;
    
    
    public: DisjointSet &operator=(DisjointSet other) {
        std::swap(nodes  , other.nodes  );
        std::swap(numSets, other.numSets);
        return *this;
    }
    
    
    
    /*---- Methods ----*/
    
    // Returns the number of elements among the set of disjoint sets; this was the number passed
    // into the constructor and is constant for the lifetime of the object. All the other methods
    // require the argument elemIndex to satisfy 0 <= elemIndex < getNumberOfElements().
    public: S getNumberOfElements() const {
        return static_cast<S>(nodes.size());
    }
    
    
    // Returns the number of disjoint sets overall. This number decreases monotonically as time progresses;
    // each call to mergeSets() either decrements the number by one or leaves it unchanged. 0 <= result <= getNumberOfElements().
    public: S getNumberOfSets() const {
        return numSets;
    }
    
    
    // Returns the size of the set that the given element is a member of. 1 <= result <= getNumberOfElements().
    public: S getSizeOfSet(S elemIndex) const {
        return nodes.at(getRepr(elemIndex)).size;
    }
    
    
    // Tests whether the given two elements are members of the same set. Note that the arguments are orderless.
    public: bool areInSameSet(S elemIndex0, S elemIndex1) const {
        return getRepr(elemIndex0) == getRepr(elemIndex1);
    }
    
    
    // Merges together the sets that the given two elements belong to. This method is also known as "union" in the literature.
    // If the two elements belong to different sets, then the two sets are merged and the method returns true.
    // Otherwise they belong in the same set, nothing is changed and the method returns false. Note that the arguments are orderless.
    public: bool mergeSets(S elemIndex0, S elemIndex1) {
        // Get representatives
        std::size_t repr0 = getRepr(elemIndex0);
        std::size_t repr1 = getRepr(elemIndex1);
        if (repr0 == repr1)
            return false;
        
        // Compare ranks
        int cmp = nodes.at(repr0).rank - nodes.at(repr1).rank;
        // Note: The computation of cmp does not overflow. 0 <= ranks[i] <= SCHAR_MAX,
        // so SCHAR_MIN <= -SCHAR_MAX <= ranks[i] - ranks[j] <= SCHAR_MAX.
        // The result actually fits in a signed char, and with sizeof(char) <= sizeof(int),
        // the promotion to int still guarantees the result fits.
        if (cmp == 0)  // Increment repr0's rank if both nodes have same rank
            nodes.at(repr0).rank++;
        else if (cmp < 0)  // Swap to ensure that repr0's rank >= repr1's rank
            std::swap(repr0, repr1);
        
        // Graft repr1's subtree onto node repr0
        nodes.at(repr1).parent = repr0;
        nodes.at(repr0).size += nodes.at(repr1).size;
        nodes.at(repr1).size = 0;
        numSets--;
        return true;
    }
    
    
    // For unit tests. This detects many but not all invalid data structures, throwing an exception
    // if a structural invariant is known to be violated. This always returns silently on a valid object.
    public: void checkStructure() const {
        S numRepr = 0;
        S i = 0;
        for (const Node &node : nodes) {
            bool isRepr = node.parent == i;
            if (isRepr)
                numRepr++;
            
            bool ok = true;
            ok &= 0 <= node.parent && safeLessThan(node.parent, nodes.size());
            ok &= 0 <= node.rank && (isRepr || node.rank < nodes.at(node.parent).rank);
            ok &= 0 <= node.size && safeLessEquals(node.size, nodes.size());
            ok &= (!isRepr && node.size == 0) || (isRepr && node.size >= (static_cast<S>(1) << node.rank));
            if (!ok)
                throw std::logic_error("Assertion error");
            i++;
        }
        if (!(0 <= numSets && numSets == numRepr && safeLessEquals(numSets, nodes.size())))
            throw std::logic_error("Assertion error");
    }
    
    
    // (Private) Returns the representative element for the set containing the given element. This method is also
    // known as "find" in the literature. Also performs path compression, which alters the internal state to
    // improve the speed of future queries, but has no externally visible effect on the values returned.
    private: S getRepr(S elemIndex) const {
        // Follow parent pointers until we reach a representative
        S parent = nodes.at(elemIndex).parent;
        while (true) {
            S grandparent = nodes.at(static_cast<std::size_t>(parent)).parent;
            if (grandparent == parent)
                return static_cast<std::size_t>(parent);
            nodes.at(static_cast<std::size_t>(elemIndex)).parent = grandparent;  // Partial path compression
            elemIndex = parent;
            parent = grandparent;
        }
    }
    
    
    private: static bool safeLessThan(S x, std::size_t y) {
        return (std::is_signed<S>::value && x < 0) ||
            static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<S>::type>(x) < y;
    }
    
    
    private: static bool safeLessEquals(S x, std::size_t y) {
        return (std::is_signed<S>::value && x < 0) ||
            static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<S>::type>(x) <= y;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: Given that you asked for advice on the `public:`/`private:` style, why have you _ignored all the answers_ (which unanimously advised against the unusual style you have used)?

Comment: @TobySpeight I found this style to be easier to read and maintain for me. I did initially learn C++ on the old style, and found myself often anxiously scanning upward to figure out what the most recent access modifier was.

Comment: I guess the question then becomes, "_Why did you even ask?_"  I for one certainly find it harder to read than normal code.  And you wouldn't need it so much if you hadn't written all the function definitions inline.

Comment: "found myself often anxiously scanning upward to figure out what the most recent access modifier was"  that begs the real question:  why do you ever even need to do that?

Comment: @JDługosz 0) When reading code to bring it into human memory. 1) When reordering or adding members/methods/fields.

Comment: The "section" of document API vs that of internal implementation details is so fundamental that I'm never confused as to which I'm reading, or which group I should add something to.  When reading the code it doesn't matter... that only makes a difference _outside_ that class, calling in.

Comment: Do you use `rank` for anything? Also, is there any other reason you prefer one node over the other as the representative? If no to both, choose the smaller as representative and there is a 2-pass algorithm to ensure all paths are fully compressed, regardless their length before.

Comment: @Deduplicator I compare ranks when merging, which guarantees O(log n) tree height. While this is correct, now that I think more, I can just get rid of the rank field, and merge by size instead. It will still guarantee O(log n) height.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use `include` guards instead of `#pragma once`

The use of `#pragma once`, while common, is not standard C++.  Use include guards instead as:

```
#ifndef DISJOINT_SET_HPP
#define DISJOINT_SET_HPP
// your header here
#endif // DISJOINT_SET_HPP
```

See [SF.8](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf8-use-include-guards-for-all-h-files) for details.

### Don't mark every data member with `public` or `private`

If you are uniquely writing in this style, then almost by definition, everyone else who uses your code will find it that much more difficult to read and understand your code.  Inserting unnecessary keywords adds visual clutter rather than clarity.

### Avoid unneeded casts

The `getRepr()` function is declared as returning type `S`, but the return statement within it is this:

```
return static_cast<std::size_t>(parent);
```

That makes no sense at all because `parent` is already declared to be of type `S`.

### Give better messages in exceptions

In the `checkStructure()` function,  the code checks to verify a large number of predicates, collapsing them all into a single `bool`.  If any of the conditions fails, the caller gets only the vague "Assertion error" message.  At this point, the structure is somehow corrupted and no longer usable, which represents a rather catastrophic failure of the structure.  For that reason, I'd suggest either writing each clause as a separate `throw` with a clear message or using old-fashioned `assert` which is likely to be the better choice in this case.

### Move error checking to compile time where practical

The constructor currently looks like this:

```
public: explicit DisjointSet(S numElems) :
        numSets(numElems) {
    if (numElems < 0)
        throw std::domain_error("Number of elements must be non-negative");
    if (!safeLessEquals(numElems, SIZE_MAX))
        throw std::length_error("Number of elements too large");
    nodes.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(numElems));
    for (S i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
        nodes.push_back(Node{i, 0, 1});
}
```

However, if we look carefully at this, both of the checks could actually be done at compile-time instead.  That suggests that the use of C++20 `requires` or C++11 `enable_if`.  Here I'm using the C++14 `enable_if_t` which is just a convenience function:

```
template <typename S, 
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<S>::value>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<S>::value> 
>
class DisjointSet final {
```

Now if we attempt to create something invalid like `DisjoinSet<float> ds(3);` we get a much clearer error versus a relatively obscure and unhelpful error pointing to `safeLessEquals` or `checkStructure`.

### Provide sensible default values where practical

The `Node` structure is only used internally to the `DisjointSet` class and is only created in the constructor of `DisjointSet`.  For that reason, I'd suggest declaring it like this:

```
struct Node final {
    mutable S parent;
    signed char rank = 0;
    S size = 1;
    Node& operator++() { ++parent; return *this; }
};
```

If you're wondering about the operator, that's part of the next suggestion.

### Use standard library functions where practical

I would suggest rewriting the constructor for `DisjointSet` like this:

```
explicit DisjointSet(S numElems) 
    : numSets(numElems) 
    , nodes(numElems) 
{
    std::iota(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), Node{0});
}
```

Note that this also assumes that we declare `numSets` before `nodes` so as not to confuse the reader.  (Elements are initialized in declaration order.)  In C++20, one could likely use a `range` and make this even more efficient.

### Don't hide a loop return condition

The `getRepr()` function has a `while(true)`, but actually returns when the parent and grandparent are the same.  I'd suggest rewriting that so that the looping exit condition is part of the loop rather than hidden within the body.  For example, one way to rewrite would be this:

```
S getRepr(S elemIndex) const {
    while (nodes.at(elemIndex).parent != nodes.at(nodes.at(elemIndex).parent).parent) {
        auto parent = nodes.at(elemIndex).parent;
        // set parent = grandparent
        nodes.at(elemIndex).parent = nodes.at(parent).parent;
        elemIndex = parent;
    }
    return nodes.at(elemIndex).parent;
}
```

### Define helper functions to improve readability

All of the parent and grandparent code gives the function above, even in its rewritten version, some clutter.  We can greatly improve readability with the use of two helper functions:

```
S parentOf(S elemIndex) const {
    return nodes.at(elemIndex).parent;
}
// sets new parent and returns previous value
S setParent(S elemIndex, S newparent) const { 
    auto oldparent{parentOf(elemIndex)};
    nodes.at(elemIndex).parent = newparent;
    return oldparent;
}
```

Now we can rewrite `getRepr` like this:

```
S getRepr(S elemIndex) const {
    // Follow parent pointers until we reach a representative
    for (const auto curr = parentOf(elemIndex); curr != parentOf(curr); )  {
        // set parent = grandparent
        elemIndex = setParent(elemIndex, parentOf(curr));
    }
    return parentOf(elemIndex);
}
```

I find that easier to read and reason about and it's shorter.

Comment: I disagree about `#pragma once`.  All compilers support it, and if I ever do come across one that doesn't, I want to use an automated tool to put in the include guards *properly*.  So many people do it wrong, using reserved names or names that are laughably non-unique.  I made that decision in 1997 and never needed to.  I think we'll see headers go away before we see `#pragma once` not work.

Comment: I do a lot of embedded systems work and have used compilers which do not support `#pragma once`.  It's an [old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the fact remains that it is non-standard and implementation defined.

Comment: Well, if you do use an include guard, don't use a simple name that _might_ clash in a system with multiple libraries used.  Or even multiple copies of different versions of the _same_ library (like Boost.Serialization).

Answer (score 2):

## Prefer using `operator[]` instead of `at()`

The member function `at()` performs bounds checking, and this comes at the cost of performance. Most of the time, you already know the indices you are using are valid. The exception is when someone can pass arbitrary values to public member functions such as `areInSameSet()`, so ideally you do the bounds checking at the top of such functions, if at all. Consider that the user of this class already knows the number of elements of the set, so it's unlikely they would ever call member functions with incorrect indices.

## Use `uint8_t` for `rank`

In the comments you say that `rank` is never negative, but then you explicitly declare it to be `signed`. I would make it an `uint8_t`, as this tells you it's never going to be negative, and it's being used to hold an integer, not a character.

Answer (score 2):

#### High-level design:

All the other answers went over the minutiae quite sufficiently, but this is where about 66% savings are easily achieved.

There are some questionable design-decisions, which complicate the code and might just bite you hard:

1. Any query of nodes will always try to compress the path.

   While it is a good idea not to redo the work needlessly, this means that the constant interface is neither reentrancy nor, as there is no internal locking, concurrency safe.

   Why not have a read-only interface and a mutable interface, letting the caller decide on his requirements? Also, add a function optimizing the set for querying.
2. `rank` is useless, as there is a better way to limit the depth of trees.

   - It bloats a `Node` by half.
   - The rank of an interior-node is irrelevant, as it is never exposed nor acted on.
   - The rank of a root node is a simple function of the count of its descendants: \$rank = \lceil ld(size)\rceil\$
   - Still, no need to calculate it, as only relative rank is needed for limiting depth, which is easily done directly comparing `size`.
3. Any `Node` always uses either `size` or `parent`. Combine them for saving half the space, if more nodes are needed let them choose a bigger type.

   Half the range for ids, half for sizes (without zero).

Comment: I essentially agree with you. 1) The fast path where a node's parent is a representative is quite reasonable. Always-compressing is necessary to achieve amortized O(log* n) time instead of O(log n) time. It is true that it throws a wrench into concurrency, and a strict const method has a valid use-case. 2) You are right and I realized this independently today; I already effected the changes on my website version. 3) I realized this too and effected the changes in the [Rust version](https://www.nayuki.io/res/disjoint-set-data-structure/disjointset.rs) today.

Comment: @Nayuki Yes, the constant interface would have worse time unless the structure was prepared. Still, there is a reason I also hinted at providing a function to optimize the whole thing. Needs just one slightly worse than linear pass (because of the code limiting depth) and a linear pass. An interesting alternative would be the option of copying or moving to a frozen type, with the optimization running automatically just before. And that one could also be paired with a structure optimized for merging without queries, and then fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `S` for size type? You can just use `std::size_t`

nondefault assignment operator with default copy constructor is unidiomatic, just let your assignment operator as `DisjointSet& operator=(const DisjointSet& other) = default;`

Setting `getRepr` as `const` but mutating `parent` inside looks very awkward, just make `getRepr` as non-const (and give a better function name)

Comment: I guess the reason for the awkward assignment operator is to force the use of the `explicit` copy-constructor.  Not sure it's the best solution to the problem, though.

Comment: @frozenca The comment at the top of the class says, "The parameter `S` can be any integer type, such as `size_t`. For any given `S`, the maximum number of sets is `S_MAX`. Using a smaller type like `int8_t` can help save memory compared to `uint64_t`."

Comment: @TobySpeight Correct. I want to make copies explicit (kind of like Rust) because copying a big vector is considered expensive. I want to avoid what happened with this [thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162877/disjoint-set-data-structure/162935#162935).

Comment: But normal C++ programmers don't make that mistake.  Passing by const reference is such a basic thing and a code review issue for newbes.  You're not writing a library to hand-hold inexperienced C++ programmers who aren't used to value semantics, but a normal production library, right?